# location data from web application without gps

Tags: php, javascript, browser, gps, location

While browsing the net I noticed some ad ask me if I would like to meet women from my suburb. How do these ads get my location data?

I use this data in my own web application. What sort of web stack do they use? Is this possible in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a coarse geographic location from a database that maps IP addresses to locations. It's called GeoIP. See [PHP: GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) or Google for GeoIP for more information.

Comment: thats pretty cool! do you happen to know what sort of accuracy it give. for eg: within a couple of kilometres

Comment: It depends on the quality of the database, how frequently it is updated. You can often get accuracy to the city.